# Laravel Eloquent Query with Specific softDeleted() Records

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm building an api with Laravel 5.3, which I need to expose some user records. I have no problem getting all the the following:

```
User::all();

User::all()->withTrashed()->where('status_id', 2);
```

But how would I combine these to show all regular users + deleted users, but only if the deleted users have a status_id = 2?

```
all users + deleted users with status_id of 2
```

To add additional clarification, I'm essentially trying to combine the following queries:

```
User::all() + User::onlyTrashed->where('status_id', 2);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
User::all()->withTrashed()
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->orWhere(function($query) {
        return $query->whereNull('deleted_at')->where('status_id', 2);
    })
    ->get();
```